# Linux used for embedded systems/electronics/control

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, embedded, raspberry-pi

I'm new with Linux and programming in general and was wondering what the advantage would be as to using a Linux OS vs. just writing to the same processor in C. I keep seeing things about Linux being used in Raspberry Pi applications. Why is it so prevalent there? Why not a C variant like in microcontrollers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raspberry pi processor is considerably more powerful than a microcontroller.  It is confusing in that the size and price of the board are similar to microcontroller boards.  It is a linux capable processor though.  Understand that the target market for the Raspberry Pi is to be used for education.  So naturally something like Linux is used and educational software on top of that.

Many/most programmers are not familiar or comfortable with bare metal and doing their own drivers, so linux makes that easier, you can write robot software that is no more complicated than writing any other user level application, the difficult parts are buried in the operating system or other drivers.

the raspberry pi though does have very simple to program peripherals, and so far as we know it is not brickable, so it can and does make for a good bare metal system, educational or hobby.

EDIT

Bare metal has different definitions but in this context it means programming without an operating system.  What I assumed you were talking about with respect to C and microcontrollers.  For example if you want to use the uart to send characters out to a terminal of some sort, with an operating system it is likely that somewhere in the mass called the operating system there is a uart kernel driver as well as some application level api of some sort so that you dont have to know anything about the uart.  But in a bare metal environment, you dont have that operating system or apis, now often someone somewhere has something that to the programmer resembles an operating system in that they have just some apis they can call (the arduino experience for example being a well done one), in this case though other than the manual being pretty bad the peripherals in the raspberry pi are simpler than equivalent peripherals in other chips.

Brickable.  Over time improvements have been made for redundant and other solutions to avoid this, but assume you have a computer the processor boots off of a rom (basically what you are reading this on is one of those computers), sometimes you can update your rom for whatever (bios upgrade in the case of a pc).  If that upgrade processor in any other way that rom gets corrupt and the boot code instead crashes the computer rather than booting it.  If you dont have a simple enough solution to fix that at your home on your desk or wherever you are doing development or using that computer then it is not much more use to you on that desk than a brick or other paperweight.  That doesnt mean that if you return it somewhere there isnt a special cable or other set of tools that you may not readily have that can recover that flash and bring it to life.  The worst case is a soldering iron to remove the flash and solder back a pre-programmed one that in theory works.  In the case of the raspberry pi that rom is the flash on the sd card, and it is easily removed by you at your desk to be reprogrammed at any time it gets erased or corrupt.  So far as we know if there is a rom in the chip for the gpu and if it is erasable and programmable in circuit then there is a possiblity that code might erase it and brick the chip.  So far as I know that is not the case the only way to prevent your raspberry pi from booting is to not have or have an sd card with a bad program on it or erased or garbage.

A driver is a general term for some code that manages a peripheral.  A uart driver for example has the knowledge of the registers for that specific uart, on the other side of that driver is a more generic ideally api or at least hides some of the details to the user at that level.  An operating system like linux or windows or whatever have kernel modules that one side is the hardware the other side its api conforms to that operating system such that you can add your raspberry pi uart to the linux kernel as a generic tty serial device and any software in the kernel or application space that wants to use a generic tty serial device can now use your raspberry pi uart.  It is just a general term where have some software that manages a peripheral and has the knowledge for that peripheral and in some way hides that knowledge to the api above it so that person doesnt have to know the nitty gritty details.

Comment: Could you help me to understand what you mean by "driver", "bare metal", and "brickable" in context here?

Comment: Dude. *Applause*. I literally can't thank you enough. This is exactly why I love these forums. I will surely be paying it forward. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Using an OS simplifies many of your tasks since it comes standard with features like hard drive / file system and memory management, implementing services and complex protocols along with many others.. However if you don't need any of these features, You might get away without an OS, in a standalone system with little outside interface.

Answer (score 1):

Answering directly your question - advantages are as :

- Linux, in fact, an industrial standard with the much faster development process, which brings to the scene all the new sources for supporting the modern elementary base: CPUs, MCUs, devices, drivers, chips and others different technologies at various layers. So it covers much more features than any Operating System does. It's also a huge enhancement of compatibility.
- Linux is open source, its code are observed and criticized by the millions of specialists all over the world, so it's mostly robust.
- Linux is free, you get the Kernel and all amazing features for free and you will not have to pay for this in the commercial serial production (many other OSes "asks" a fee per the unit of product)